# Passing in a custom selector implementation

Tags: objective-c, selector, objective-c-blocks, imp

Supposed I have two objective-c classes, `LBFoo` and `LBBar`.

In `LBFoo` I have a method that looks like this:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithFoo:(NSNumber*)anArgument
{
  if(anArgument.intValue > 2)
    [LBBar doSomethingWithLBBar];
  else
    [LBBar doSomethingElseWithLBBar];
}
```

What I would like to do instead is pass an implementation to `LBBar` that was not declared ahead of time. (As in dynamically override an existing @selector within `LBBar`)

I know that an `IMP` type exists, is it possible to pass an `IMP` to a class in order to change its selector implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `method_setImplementation(Method method, IMP imp)` function in [objective-c runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).

if you want to set an instance method, it would work something like this

```
method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod([yourClass class], @selector(yourMethod)), yourIMP);
```

if you want a class method, just use `class_getClassMethod` instead of `class_getInstanceMethod`. The arguments should be the same.

that's all there is to it. Note that IMP is just a void function pointer with the first 2 parameters being `id self` and `SEL _cmd`

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use the runtime functions to do something like this,* but I'd suggest that this is *exactly* the sort of problem that [Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) were introduced to solve. They allow you to pass around a chunk of executable code -- your method can actually accept a Block as an argument and run it.

Here's a SSCCE:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef dispatch_block_t GenericBlock;

@interface Albatross : NSObject 
- (void)slapFace:(NSNumber *)n usingFish:(GenericBlock)block;
@end

@implementation Albatross

- (void)slapFace:(NSNumber *)n usingFish:(GenericBlock)block
{
    if( [n intValue] > 2 ){
        NSLog(@"Cabbage crates coming over the briny!");
    }
    else {
        block();    // Execute the block
    }
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Albatross * p = [Albatross new];
        [p slapFace:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] usingFish:^{
            NSLog(@"We'd like to see the dog kennels, please.");
        }];
         [p slapFace:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] usingFish:^{
            NSLog(@"Lemon curry?");
        }];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

*Note that using `method_setImplementation()` will change the code that's used every time that method is called in the future from anywhere -- it's a persistent change.

Comment: Thanks for this Josh, I am actually intending for the change to be permanent. Performing a bit of meta programming via dynamic method generation.

Comment: You should look at the ["Messaging"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104), "Dynamic Method Resolution", and "Message Forwarding" chapters in the ObjC Runtime Programming Guide, then. You'll probably end up using `method_setImplementation()` anyways, but there is some higher-level support for dynamic message handling built into `NSObject`.